# How to get data from multiple tables and send to html with '->with()' in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have to tables 'users' and 'departments' and I want to get data from both tables and put in html form.
here is my code which not working because there is something missing in it.
here is the code of controller:

```
 public  function showProfileForm($id){
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    $dpt = DB::table('departments')->orderBy('department_name','asc')->get();
    return view('profile.showProfile')->with(['selDpt', $dpt, 'user', $user]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get() method retrieve data as a multi-dimensional array. So when you will retrieve only one array then you have to use first() method at the end of the query. So just Change the query from

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
to 
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
```

Now, You have to pass data by `array`. So just change the line

```
return view('profile.showProfile')->with(['selDpt', $dpt, 'user', $user]);
To
return view('profile.showProfile')->with(['selDpt' => $dpt, 'user' => $user]);
```

**shoProfile.blade.php**

You have to use `$selDpt` & `$user` variable for use or echo data. 
Hope it will work.

Learn more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: now I am able to get departments via {{ $dpt->department_name }}, but when try to get user name with {{ $user->name }} it give error that 'Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance'

Comment: while 'name' exists in my 'users' table

Comment: @UmairGul just try to change the last method in your query. So it should not get(); it should be first(); Because it will retrieve only one array. I updated my answers. Please look it.

Comment: happy to know that, my answer is helpful for you. You're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to pass multiple variables to a view:

```
return view('profile.showProfile', [
    'selDpt' => $dpt,
    'user' => $user
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: now I am able to get departments via {{ $dpt->department_name }}, but when try to get user name with {{ $user->name }} it give error that 'Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance'

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use PHP function `compact()`. http://php.net/compact

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
$dpt = DB::table('departments')->orderBy('department_name','asc')->get();

return view('profile.showProfile', compact('dpt', 'user'));
```

You will have `$user` and `$dpt` in your view.